# Javafx: Recovering the text of a label contained within a pane through pane.getChildren().get(index)

Tags: java, javafx

This is a problem I've been trying to deal with for a good hour now, so I figured I might as well ask this question. My goal/question is about the behaviour of the list supplied by pane.getChildren(). To explain better, here's a bit of example code.

```
VBox pane1 = new VBox();
Label label1 = new Label("a");
Label label2 = new Label("b");
pane1.getChildren().addAll(label1,label2);
System.out.println(pane1.getChildren().size());
for (int i=0; i<pane1.getChildren().size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + pane1.getChildren().get(i).(??????????)
}
```

The list pane1.getChildren() is of a size 2, but the pane1.getChildren().get(i) doesn't allow me to use Label related methods (such as getText(), which is the one I'm interested in accessing). What exactly is happening here, why isn't pane1.getChildren().get(i) acknowledged as a Label?

Also worth adding, that if i run

```
for (int i=0; i<pane1.getChildren().size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i + pane1.getChildren().get(i).getClass().getName());
}
```

the console output says, that the name of the class is "javafx.scene.control.Label".

I'd love some clarification on this little problem, and thank you in advance!

Comment: Just downcast it. But why do you want to do this anyway? You already have the references to the labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Pane.getChildren()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html#getChildren--) returns an `ObservableList<Node>`, so `pane1.getChildren().get(i)` has a compile-time type of `Node`, not `Label`.

It's not clear why you need to do this: you already have the references to the labels without iterating through the pane's list of children. So you can just do

```
Stream.of(label1, label2).map(Label::getText).forEach(text -> {
  // whatever you need to do with the text...
});
```

If you really want to get this from the pane's children list, just do the obvious downcast:

```
for (Node n : pane1.getChildren()) {
   String text = ((Label) n).getText();
   // ...
}
```

or

```
pane1.getChildren().stream()
    .map(Label.class::cast)
    .map(Label::getText)
    .forEach(text -> {
        // whatever you need to do with text...
    });
```

but of course this will not work (without extra checks) if you put something in the pane that is not a label.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! A bit of a programming begineer here, so I still forget certain concepts.

Comment: @ingrm The basic point is that the compiler has no idea that the things in the list are `Label`s. You can add many other types of thing to that list.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to downcast it can be done in a stream:

```
pane1.getChildren()
     .stream()
     .filter(Label.class::isInstance)
     .map(Label.class::cast)
     .forEach(label -> System.out.println(label.getText()));
```

This filters all children to just be labels, then maps them as such.